# Fastest way to update the activity for all the orientations

Tags: android, orientation

In my android `Activity` I need to update the `camera` preview orientation and the UI according to the device Orientation`. And I need all orientations for my activity namely`Portrait`,`Landscape`,`Landscape reverse`and`portrait reverse`.

I use the Android API demo for the camera preview. I found that when I use `fullSensor` for orientation setting in my `AndroidManifest.xml` and call the `setCameraDisplayOrientation()` on `surfaceChanged()` method of the Preview class(I am referring to the `CameraPreview.java` in the API demo sources) I get the desired behavior.

But there is a big delay on each orientation switch.  When I set the orientation to `Landscape` in the manifest the preview is smooth but the UI is not updating according to the device orientation. I need the orientation to be set to `Landscape` and the UI to change according to all the four orientations namely `Portrait up`, `Landscape right`, `Landscape left` and `Portrait down`. What is the optimal way of achieving the same with good performance?